# How to apply a function on a pandas groupby object and save the results back into a new column of the parent dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0, 123, 342, 353, 467, 345, 789, 543, 3913], 
   ...:                    'Y': [0, 12, 23, 41, 23, 45, 23, 53, 23], 
   ...:                    'Group': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]})               

In [7]: df                                                                      
Out[7]: 
      X   Y  Group
0     0   0      0
1   123  12      1
2   342  23      2
3   353  41      0
4   467  23      1
5   345  45      2
6   789  23      0
7   543  53      1
8  3913  23      2
```

The three groups represent measurement series, and I would like to compute the euclidean distance to the preceding element for each measurement of the series and add it up per measurement. (first measurement distance = 0).

I've read all of the forum topics here on how to reassign the result of a groupby operation back to the parent dataframe. But in my case of calculating something for each entry of the dataframe (not aggregating) based on groups, i couldn't find any solution.

So I want to know how to combine these steps:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

# 1. Group data
group = df.groupby('Group')
# 2. Calculate cumulative euclidean distance for each group
group['Distance'] = group.apply(lambda row: euclidean(row['X'], row['Y']).cumsum(), axis=1)
# 3. Assign back to original dataframe
```

Step 1 is pretty straightforward. For Step 2 I tried a lot of combinations of `df.groupby.apply` and `df.groupby.apply.transform` along with defining my own functions (don't know if this will fit into a one liner). But I couldn't really get it to behave the way I want. I assume `groupby().transform()` is what I want, but I can't get it to operate row-wise.

Also for reassigning the result to my original dataframe instead to only the groupby object, I tried `df.join`, `pd.merge`, `pd.concat` and so on, but I am now at a point where I'm super confused what the difference is :D.

My desired output would be:

```
Out[7]: 
      X   Y  Group  Distance  Cumulative Distance
0     0   0      0         0                    0
1   123  12      1         0                    0 
2   342  23      2         0                    0
3   353  41      0    355.37               355.37   
4   467  23      1    344.17               344.17     
5   345  45      2     22.20                22.20    
6   789  23      0    436.37               791.74     
7   543  53      1     81.71               425.88     
8  3913  23      2   3568.07              3590.44
```

I only need the cumulative distance (again computed per group). But I listed the individual distance as intermediate step.

Comment: Why is expected 'Distance' at idx 1 & 2 `0` ?

Comment: @ChrisA they are where the group starts. Distances computed within groups.

Comment: I think your expected result is wrong. You suppose to use `euclidean(point1, point2)` which `euclidean([467, 23], [123, 12])` should yield 344.17 instead of 457.66

Comment: Sorry, I was on the run and wanted to push the question out before leaving, so I did the distances quickly in excel. I'll adapt it.

@ChrisA Yes, I want to compute the distance groupwise to the preceeding entry. so for the first entry in each group it should be 0.

Comment: Please compare your expected result with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` `apply` with `shift` to get each row previous point then use `bfill` to fill the first point with itself.

After that, create new columns with zip `X` and `Y` together.

```
df.sort_values('Group', inplace=True)
df[['X_shift', 'Y_shift']] = df.groupby('Group')[['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)).bfill()
df['point_1'] = tuple(zip(df.X, df.Y))
df['point_2'] = tuple(zip(df.X_shift, df.Y_shift))

df

      X   Y  Group  X_shift  Y_shift     point_1        point_2
0     0   0      0      0.0      0.0      (0, 0)     (0.0, 0.0)
3   353  41      0      0.0      0.0   (353, 41)     (0.0, 0.0)
6   789  23      0    353.0     41.0   (789, 23)  (353.0, 41.0)
1   123  12      1    123.0     12.0   (123, 12)  (123.0, 12.0)
4   467  23      1    123.0     12.0   (467, 23)  (123.0, 12.0)
7   543  53      1    467.0     23.0   (543, 53)  (467.0, 23.0)
2   342  23      2    342.0     23.0   (342, 23)  (342.0, 23.0)
5   345  45      2    342.0     23.0   (345, 45)  (342.0, 23.0)
8  3913  23      2    345.0     45.0  (3913, 23)  (345.0, 45.0)
```

And use `apply` to calculate euclidean distance on each point then use `groupby` with `cumsum` to get the final result.

```
df['Distance'] = df.apply(lambda row: euclidean(row.point_1, row.point_2), axis=1)

df

      X   Y  Group  X_shift  Y_shift     point_1        point_2     Distance
0     0   0      0      0.0      0.0      (0, 0)     (0.0, 0.0)     0.000000
3   353  41      0      0.0      0.0   (353, 41)     (0.0, 0.0)   355.373043
6   789  23      0    353.0     41.0   (789, 23)  (353.0, 41.0)   436.371401
1   123  12      1    123.0     12.0   (123, 12)  (123.0, 12.0)     0.000000
4   467  23      1    123.0     12.0   (467, 23)  (123.0, 12.0)   344.175827
7   543  53      1    467.0     23.0   (543, 53)  (467.0, 23.0)    81.706793
2   342  23      2    342.0     23.0   (342, 23)  (342.0, 23.0)     0.000000
5   345  45      2    342.0     23.0   (345, 45)  (342.0, 23.0)    22.203603
8  3913  23      2    345.0     45.0  (3913, 23)  (345.0, 45.0)  3568.067824
```

---

```
df['Cumulative Distance'] = df.groupby('Group').Distance.cumsum()

# Drop unuse columns
df.drop(columns=['X_shift', 'Y_shift', 'point_1', 'point_2'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df

      X   Y  Group     Distance  Cumulative Distance
0     0   0      0     0.000000             0.000000
1   123  12      1     0.000000             0.000000
2   342  23      2     0.000000             0.000000
3   353  41      0   355.373043           355.373043
4   467  23      1   344.175827           344.175827
5   345  45      2    22.203603            22.203603
6   789  23      0   436.371401           791.744445
7   543  53      1    81.706793           425.882620
8  3913  23      2  3568.067824          3590.271428
```

Comment: Testing your solution right now. Two problems I found so far: First, `df.sort_values('Group', inplace=True)` doesn't sort the index for me. My real data has 120 rows, and when sorting by group I get Group 0's indexes un-ordered like `[0, 69, 108, 30, 96...]`. I don't know why this is. Second: I have to use `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` before calculating the cumulative distance for it to work. This might be associated with the first problem. I changed the style of your code up a bit and put it into a function, so I'll further check whether the error is on my side.

Comment: Turns out your solution works perfectly on the test data I provided. The error must be hiding in the application to my real world data. Thanks alot for helping out, I'll figure it out from here.

Comment: @cripcate Can you try comment `sort_values` and replace `.apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).bfill())` in line 2?

Comment: My data wasn't sorted right before starting. It works like this:
`df[['X_shift', 'Y_shift']] = df.groupby('Group')[['ROI_X_µm', 'ROI_Y_µm']].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).bfill())`. Then
`df['P1'] = tuple(zip(df['ROI_X_µm'], df['ROI_Y_µm']))`,
`df['P2'] = tuple(zip(df['X_shift'], df['Y_shift']))`, sort:
`df.sort_values('Group', inplace=True)`
Calculate distances:
`df['Dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: euclidean(row['P1'], row['P2']), axis=1)`
`df.sort_index(inplace=True)`,
`df['Cum_Dist'] = df.groupby('Group')['Dist'].cumsum()`